# How can I use LTRIM/RTRIM to search and replace leading/trailing spaces?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of trying to clear out leading and trailing spaces from an NVARCHAR(MAX) column that is filled with prices (using NVARCHAR due to data importing from multiple operating systems with odd characters).

At this point I have a t-sql command that can remove the leading/trailing spaces from static prices.  However, when it comes to leveraging this same command to remove all prices, I'm stumped.

Here's the static script I used to remove a specific price:

```
UPDATE *tablename* set *columnname* = LTRIM(RTRIM(2.50)) WHERE cost = '2.50 ';
```

Here's what I've tried to remove all the trailing spaces:

```
UPDATE *tablename* set *columnname* LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM('[.]')) WHERE cost LIKE '[.] ';
```

I've also tried different varations of the % for random characters but at this point I'm spinning my wheels.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to run one simple command that takes off all the leading and trailing spaces in each cell of this column without modifying any of the actual column data.

Comment: in short, do you want to remove all spaces in the string?

Comment: I'd like to remove all the leading and trailing spaces in each of the cells in one specific column.  They all have either leading or trailing spaces.  I'm trying to create a report and when I attempt to convert these cells to int, I discovered the leading/trailing spaces are preventing the report data from producing.

Comment: so what's the problem of using `LTRIM(RTRIM(val))`?

Comment: set *columnname* LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM('[.]')) is the problem i think you shold set it not like it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove spaces from left/right, use LTRIM/RTRIM. What you had

```
UPDATE *tablename*
   SET *columnname* = LTRIM(RTRIM(*columnname*));
```

would have worked on ALL the rows.  To minimize updates if you don't need to update, the update code is unchanged, but the LIKE expression in the WHERE clause would have been

```
UPDATE [tablename]
   SET [columnname] = LTRIM(RTRIM([columnname]))
 WHERE 32 in (ASCII([columname]), ASCII(REVERSE([columname])));
```

Note: 32 is the ascii code for the space character.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I'm a bit new at this aspect of SQL and the info I found online was either old or way too overly complex.

Answer (score 2):

To remove spaces... please use `LTRIM`/`RTRIM`

```
 LTRIM(String)
 RTRIM(String)
```

The String parameter that is passed to the functions can be a column name, a variable, a literal string or the output of a user defined function or scalar query.

```
SELECT LTRIM(' spaces at start')
SELECT RTRIM(FirstName) FROM Customers
```

Read more: http://rockingshani.blogspot.com/p/sq.html#ixzz33SrLQ4Wi

Answer (score 1):

**LTrim function** and **RTrim function** :

- The **LTrim function** to remove **leading spaces** and the **RTrim
  function** to remove **trailing spaces** from a string variable.
- It uses the **Trim function** to **remove both types of spaces**.

  ```
                select LTRIM(RTRIM(' SQL Server '))
  ```

  output:

  ```
                           SQL Server
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is for sql server 2012, but if the same scenario for SQL Server 2017 or SQL Azure you can use `Trim` directly as below:

```
UPDATE *tablename*
   SET *columnname* = trim(*columnname*);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RTRIM(' Author ') AS Name;
```

Output will be without any trailing spaces.

Name
——————
‘    Author’

Answer (score -1):

The LTrim function to remove leading spaces and the RTrim function to remove trailing spaces from a string variable.
It uses the Trim function to remove both types of spaces and means before and after spaces of string.

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REVERSE(' NEXT LEVEL EMPLOYEE ')))

Comment: @RamPrakash Returns the reverse order of a string value.

Comment: @MuratVezir I'm aware of its functionality, I'm trying to understand, Is OP asking for reverse?