# How can remove spaces from the both side of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table T1, T1 table should be contain a column `lname`. The value of `lname` have space on both side.

I want to retrieve the name from `lname` and remove the spaces from both side.

Help me.

Comment: `LTrim(RTrim(column))`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use LTRIM and RTRIM in conjunction to remove extra spaces from both sides

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(lname)) as lname FROM T1
```

See msdn documentation on this function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx

SQL fiddle for demonstration http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec068/1

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to Trim your text, Sql is providing Inbuilt function for it

```
SELECT LTrim(RTrim(' ABC '))
```

Here in above Query you can get the text `'ABC'` with removed space from beginning and ending of the string, Same way it will work for you, try below Query.

```
SELECT LTrim(RTrim(Column_Name)) From Tbl_Test
```

For reference you can take a look at here:

1) [How can I use LTRIM/RTRIM to search and replace leading/trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431806/how-can-i-use-ltrim-rtrim-to-search-and-replace-leading-trailing-spaces)

2) http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/ltrim.php

3) http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_function_trim.php